# Count with conditional - dataframe

Tags: r, count, conditional-statements

I would like to count how many times a observation appears with the condition one column is greater than another.

For example, how many times the "A", "B" and "C" apperead counting only if the column B is greater than colun C.

```
set.seed(20170524)

A <- rep(c("A","B","C"),5)
B <- round(runif(15,0,20),0)
C <- round(runif(15,1,5),0) + B
D <- as.data.frame(cbind(A,B,C))
D <- D[order(B),]
```

Thank you!

Comment: Looks like `C` is always greater than `B` as `C <- B + round(runif(15,1,5),0) `. Or maybe I misunderstood something

Answer (score 0):

```
#firstly, those numbers got converted to factors, this is problematic.
D$B<-as.numeric(D$B)
D$C<-as.numeric(D$C)

#Then, get the counts for the A:
countA = sum(D$A=='A' & D$B < D$C)
```

Similarly for 'B' and 'C'

If there's many more than just categories "A,B,C" you might want to do a data.table for the by= option, but someone will probably be along to say that's overkill.

Comment: converting factors directly into numeric will get you the index of factor levels not the actual values. You have to pass through character format first: `D$B<-as.numeric(as.character(D$B))`

Answer (score 0):

You can use: `table(D$A[which(D$B>D$C)])`

Note that when you do `D <- as.data.frame(cbind(A,B,C))` you will get `factors` so either you transform `B` and `C` into numeric variables afterwards, or you just create directly a `data.frame` without passing through a `matrix`:

`D <- data.frame(A,B,C)`